# Displaying ComboBox items in two lines instead of displaying in one line

Tags: javafx, combobox

I am currently using JavaFx `ComboBox` and I load the options from a XML file.
The problem I have is that some items are too long and they don't fit well:
[image]

I have tried using CSS width:

```
   .combo-box {
        -fx-pref-width: 300;
    }
    .combo-box-popup > .list-view {
        -fx-pref-width: 300;
    }
```

[image]

Is it possible to display `ComboBox` items in two lines instead of displaying in one line?

Comment: You can add "\n" inside your item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to setup a custom `CellFactory` for your `ComboBox`. Within the new `ListCell` we build, we can use a simple `Label` that wraps the text for us.

Here is a complete example to demonstrate:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboBoxTextWrap extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // The ComboBox
        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();

        // Sample data
        comboBox.getItems().addAll(
                "Shorty",
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                "Shorty Jr.",
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
        );

        // Create our custom cells for the ComboBox
        comboBox.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<String>() {

            // Create a Label to store our text. We'll set it to wrap text and it's preferred width
            final Label label = new Label() {{
                setWrapText(true);
                setPrefWidth(200);
            }};

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    // Add our text to the Label
                    label.setText(item);
                    setGraphic(label);
                }
            }
        });

        // Add the combobox to the layout
        root.getChildren().add(comboBox);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

> **The Result:**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: actually .. not a good solution (what happens if the width of the combo changes ... ;). The way to go is a custom cell implementation.

Comment: @kleopatra - Challenge accepted. I will update my answer shortly, because I do agree.

Comment: Can you also set a tooltip if the text is cut off?

Comment: @trilogy - Of course. Just check the length of the `String` and add a `Tooltip` if it's longer than your desired length. You could always just add a `Tooltip` to every `Label` anyway too.

Comment: Isn't the label still being cut off at the end even though it's wrapped? To me, it seems better to wrap the `Tooltip` and keep the selections one line. But that's just me...

Comment: @trilogy - It does still cut it off. The OP may need to wrap the `Label` in a more expandable container if they want the whole thing shown. Or a larger `prefWidth` for the `Label`. The question does specifically ask how to make it more than one line, though.

Comment: *WORKS* Just pasted the ``custom cell for ComboBox`` in to my ``initialize`` method. The amazing thing is that it doesn't modify the actual ``String`` so I can compare it later to my XML to do other things :P. Thanks.